# How do I combine multiple IDs each with totals, into one total = concate? For each ID?

Tags: sql

Here's the example, 96184140 has earnings from various periods of time.

Data which I can get from combining CSV outputs, these are columns a,b,c,d Etc.

```
96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $11.36

96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $3.63

96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $3.30

96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $2.42

96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $0.99

96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $0.99

96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $0.25
```

What I'd like to have as the result:

```
96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $22.94
```

Here's another example of the starting data:

```
97678835 Photos 12/8/2015 $52.90

97678835 Photos 12/8/2015 $43.67

309957440 Illustrations 12/16/2019 $40.06

97678835 Photos 12/8/2015 $37.89

97678835 Photos 12/8/2015 $36.20

238120662 Photos 12/9/2018 $33.51

104687626 Photos 3/6/2016 $33.37

238120662 Photos 12/9/2018 $32.75

309957440 Illustrations 12/16/2019 $31.10

309957440 Illustrations 12/16/2019 $28.63

103860091 Photos 2/26/2016 $27.39

185255839 Photos 12/19/2017 $27.39

510848455 Photos 6/14/2022 $25.18

101590495 Illustrations 2/1/2016 $23.05

97678835 Photos 12/8/2015 $23.03

96184153 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $22.15

96184153 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $21.53

96184153 Illustrations 11/18/2015 $21.30

99663927 Illustrations 1/8/2016 $18.74

104687626 Photos 3/6/2016 $16.83
```

I can sort by ID, but then I get a result like the first example. Seven individual rows. I'm looking for one total for each ID?

I tried to concate but got something like

```
96184140 Illustrations 11/18/2015 ($11.36, $3.63, $3.30, Etc.)
```

Instead of just a total.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into what is called **grouping** and **aggregation**.

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT id, date, SUM(earnings) as total
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id, date
```

Comment: Thanks I'm off to try to learn that part. Great Help.